# problema con spring security y spring boot

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

estoy teniendo problemas con un metodo post y los permisos de las request.
este es el codigo de spring security.
lo que quiero hacer es que para las peticiones con "/api/**" necesite estar autenticado
si cambio la opcion athenticated() por permitAll(), me deja hacer la peticion, por lo tanto asumo que debe ser un problema de permisos con la autenticacion.
realice una impresion por consola en el controlador de autenticacion para verificar que el usuario se autentique y me dice que el usuario esta autenticado, no se cual podria ser el problema

adjunto el jwtRequestFilter y el corsConfiguration, por si es necesario, debido a que tambien tuve varios problemas con el anteriormente.

```
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            return  http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll() 
                    .requestMatchers("/authenticate", "/sign-up").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                   .addFilterBefore(authFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                   .build();
    }

@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public void createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws BadCredentialsException,DisabledException,UsernameNotFoundException,IOException,JSONException,ServletException {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        }catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Constraseña incorrecta");
        }catch (DisabledException disabledExcemption) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "Usuario no activado");
            return;
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        User user = userRepository.findFirstByEmail(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        response.getWriter().write(new JSONObject()
                .put("userId", user.getId())
                .put("role", user.getUserRole())
                .toString()
                );
        String token = TOKEN_PREFIX + jwt;
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Header", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Header", "Authorization,X-PINGGOTHER,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,X-CustomHeader");
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, token);
        
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        // Verificar si el usuario está autenticado
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            log.info("usuario authenticado");
        } else {
            log.info("usuario no authenticado");
        }
        
    }



`@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("*");
                log.info("entro");
            }
        };
    }

    @Component
    public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
        
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
        
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
        
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain filterChain)throws ServletException,IOException{
            String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            String token = null;
            String username = null;
            
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("bearer ")) {
                token = authHeader.substring(7);
                username = jwtUtil.exctractUsername(token);
            }
            
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                
                if(jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    
    }
```